# listen android volume keys down and up events after phone locked

Tags: android, key

I am developing an app which needs to listen volume keys down and up events to do something.When the screen is bright,i can override onKeyDown and oneKeyUp methods.But if the phone is locked,this method is no possible to work out. I want to know how can i achieve it after the phone locked?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SettingsObserver to catch volume change as a backup solution :

```
SettingsObserver audioObserver = new SettingsObserver(context, new Handler());
```

And for the settings observer :

```
public class SettingsObserver extends ContentObserver {

    /**
     * Application context
     */
    private Context context = null;


    /**
     * build SettingsObserver
     *
     * @param context retrieve application context to look for Audio Manager service
     * @param handler The handler to run {@link #onChange} on, or null if none.
     */
    public SettingsObserver(Context context, Handler handler, DroidEvent manager) {
        super(handler);

        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);

        AudioManager audio = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

        if (audio != null) {
            byte newVolumeMedia = (byte) audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            byte newVolumeSystem = (byte) audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
            byte newVolumeRing = (byte) audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
            byte newVolumeNotification = (byte) audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
            byte newVolumeDtmf = (byte) audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_DTMF);
            byte newVolumeVoiceCall = (byte) audio.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
        }
    }
}
```

And register your ContentObserver :

```
context.getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true, audioObserver);
```

This way you can retrieve all type of volume event which will make  you know that volume key has been pressed up or down

Comment: thanks for your answer! Actually, i need both down and up events of volume keys. When volume keys were pressed down, i will start doing one thing, and when volume keys were loosened, i will stop that thing. So,observing the the value of volume doesn't work, for example,if the volume has been largest or smallest or phone is locked,observation will not work. In short, i don't care about the value of volume,but volume keys press down and up events, what's more, when i press the keys,the value of volume will not change.